# Working on Data exploratory and I am now in the Cleaning data level

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dataset, eda

I am wondering when I have a date in my dataset and there are NULL values in date columns what is the best way to impute the date Null values in a datetime dtype?!

As for the floats values I have already imputed them with the mean but I am stuck dealing with the dates.
Any suggestions, please!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Rasha to stackoverflow,

Well to your question - Missing values are imputed for continous data, classified data based on business justification or by data interpretation and for a date kind of value, it very much depends upon the data again.

#### Datetime Series Data

For an instance if you have data related to stock prices and the dates are missing you could impute missing values by backfilling [Refer Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

#### Random Date Data

If its random data with no sequence to dates, then may be at broader level you can analyze the data by some plots to come to conclusion of some major events occuring over particular range of dates and may be you use that to fill the missing values if those records fall under the events.

##### Final Words

It could be better if you could help us with the data context, what the data is about and some background of it. Which would help us in answering better.